# Javascript: Add text next to checkbox label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this checkbox:

```
<div id="div_id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="form-group">
<label for="id_diag-diagnosis_option_0" class="control-label col-md-3 requiredField">
Option<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label>
<div class="controls col-md-8"><label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_1" value="b" >b</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_2" value="a" >a</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_3" value="c" >c</label>
</div></div>
```

And I'm using this javascript to add an html link to each selected checkbox.

```
$("input[name='diag-diagnosis_option']").change(function () {
                        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                            var option = $(this).val();
                            alert(option);
                            $(this).after("<a href='#'>here</a>");
                        }
                    });
```

The text is printed on the left side of the label. Is it possible to print it after the label, e.g. on the right of b?

See a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zinonas/ucnepxqt/).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @WhiteHat that is not a problem, if you do close it chrome removes it, not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to traverse up to the parent with `.parent()` and  use jQuery's [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function:

```
$(this).parent().append("<a href='#'>here</a>");
```

Check fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ucnepxqt/5/

Comment: Thanks! This it. I have another question please. If I uncheck a checkbox, is there a way to remove the added `"<a href='#'>here</a>"`?

Comment: yes of course - check updated fiddle. But i would recommend adding class to <a/> tag if possible. Let's say 'a-class', and instead of `$this.siblings('a').length` check for `$this.siblings('.a-class').length`. This way it will be more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("input[name='diag-diagnosis_option']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option);
        $(this).parent().append("<a href='#'>here</a>");
    }
});
```